# MPMoviePlayerViewController only display video but not playing the audio iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

Forgive me if this question has been asked already, but I've looked everywhere and all I can find is old questions from iOS 5.0 and people have the opposite problem.

My problem is I have created a video I would like to use in my application, and I recently added audio to it. The video plays fine with no problems, but the audio does not play. If I play the video in any video player in my computer, the sound is there so I cant figure out what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
var movieViewController: MPMoviePlayerViewController?

func playVideoUsingViewController() {
    if let
        path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wakyIntro", ofType: "mp4"),
        url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path),
        movieViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url) {
            self.movieViewController = movieViewController
            movieViewController.moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
            movieViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = .None
            movieViewController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            movieViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
            self.showViewController(movieViewController, sender: self)
            println("Movie loaded")
    } else {
        println("Video failed")
    }
}
```

Then I just call it from my ViewController:

```
func mainMenuViewControllerDidPressPlay(mainMenuViewController: MainMenuViewController) {
    game?.runAction(pressButton)
    if !videoPlayed{
        playVideoUsingViewController()
    } else if !gameStarted {
        gameStarted = true
        game?.bird.startAnimation(game!)
        game?.bird.startPhysics()
    }
    self.hideViewController(mainMenuViewController)

}
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check 1 possible reason, is your device in silent mode (silent key is turned off). its just a possible reason except all coding related stuffs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution in swift based on @user2709666's response

```
    var session: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()        
    session.setCategory("AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback", withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker, error: nil)
```

Call this before playing the video.

**Edit for Swift 2.2 :**

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a session of AVAudioSession.
Following is the code:

```
var session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
session.SetCategory(new NSString("AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback"), AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker, out error);

if (error != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(error);
}
```

and add this before your video player. I am sure this will work for you, I got the same issue before.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this fixed the problem right up, though I had to modify the code a bit. What language is that? Is not quite swift I noticed.

Comment: hI, This is c# language and i make Ios code uasing xamarin , Conceptually it is everything same like api names , just launguge syntax is diff ;)